I'm trying to install Elasticsearch (8.10.2) on my Windows machine, but encountering errors related to plugin types and configuration mismatches
When starting Elasticsearch using elasticsearch.bat, I'm seeing the following errors related to plugin types:
2024-07-09 16:27:58,817 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for IfFileName
2024-07-09 16:27:58,823 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for IfFileName
2024-07-09 16:27:58,843 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for IfAccumulatedFileSize
2024-07-09 16:27:58,844 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for IfFileName

These errors indicate that Elasticsearch is unable to locate necessary plugins (IfFileName and IfAccumulatedFileSize) required for log rolling policies.
Ownership Mismatch Warning:
I also get a warning:
Aborting auto configuration because of config dir ownership mismatch. Config dir is owned by BUILTIN\Administrators but auto-configuration directory would be owned by DESKTOP-9RS8J15\Lenovo

This warning suggests a directory ownership conflict where Elasticsearch's configuration directory has differing ownership permissions between BUILTIN\Administrators and DESKTOP-9RS8J15\Lenovo.
Here's a snippet from my log4j2.properties configuration file (log4j2.properties):
######## Server JSON ############################
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = rolling
appender.rolling.fileName = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}${sys:file.separator}${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}_server.json
appender.rolling.layout.type = ECSJsonLayout
appender.rolling.layout.dataset = elasticsearch.server

appender.rolling.filePattern = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}${sys:file.separator}${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.json.gz
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size = 128MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.fileIndex = nomax
appender.rolling.strategy.action.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.action.basepath = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.type = IfFileName
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.glob = ${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}-*
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.type = IfAccumulatedFileSize
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.exceeds = 2GB

######## Server -  old style pattern ###########
appender.rolling_old.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling_old.name = rolling_old
appender.rolling_old.fileName = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}${sys:file.separator}${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}.log
appender.rolling_old.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling_old.layout.pattern = [%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{1.}] [%node_name]%marker %m%n

appender.rolling_old.filePattern = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}${sys:file.separator}${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling_old.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling_old.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling_old.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling_old.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling_old.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling_old.policies.size.size = 128MB
appender.rolling_old.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling_old.strategy.fileIndex = nomax
appender.rolling_old.strategy.action.type = Delete
appender.rolling_old.strategy.action.basepath = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}
appender.rolling_old.strategy.action.condition.type = IfFileName
appender.rolling_old.strategy.action.condition.glob = ${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}-*
appender.rolling_old.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.type = IfAccumulatedFileSize
appender.rolling_old.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.exceeds = 2GB
################################################

I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve these issues:
How can I correctly configure or install the required plugins (IfFileName and IfAccumulatedFileSize) for Elasticsearch?
What steps should I take to resolve the ownership mismatch warning related to the config directory?
Is there a recommended approach to ensure Elasticsearch uses my specified JAVA_HOME (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21.0.1) instead of the bundled JDK?
Any insights or assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Are you by any chance using a Turkish or Azeri locale?

yes, im using Turkish

This question is similar to: Log4j2 encoding issue. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
